# The best way to convert Dynamic SQL to C#/Linq while joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to find the best way to convert the following dynamic SQL snippet to C# / Linq. The question is complicated by the use of multiple tables within the dynamic SQL.

I've examined the possibility of using the Dynamic Linq Library as well as the PredicateBuilder - though neither provides an elegant solution as I have several other such examples to convert in addition to the following example.

Would someone mind pointing to some relevant resources and provide a brief example?

```
Declare @addressID BIGINT, @ServiceCategoryID BIGINT, @ServiceID BIGINT, @ProviderIsSlidingPaymentScale BIT, @ProviderServiceToKeywordKeywordID NVARCHAR(MAX), @GenderServed BIGINT, @AgeGroupServed BIGINT, @proximity FLOAT 
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT Provider.ID, Provider.Name, '''' AS IndividualName, ParentProviderID,
        NoteMultiLingualFieldID,ProviderGroupID FROM Provider
        INNER JOIN ProviderService ON Provider.ID = ProviderService.ProviderID 
        INNER JOIN Service ON ProviderService.ServiceID = Service.ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ProviderServiceToKeyword ON Provider.ID = ProviderServiceToKeyword.ProviderID 
        AND ProviderService.ServiceID = ProviderServiceToKeyword.ServiceID          
        LEFT JOIN ProviderServiceToAgeGenderServed AS PSAGS1 ON PSAGS1.ServiceID = Service.ID 
        AND PSAGS1.ProviderID = Provider.ID AND PSAGS1.Type = ''AgeServed''     
        LEFT JOIN ProviderServiceToAgeGenderServed AS PSAGS2  ON PSAGS2.ServiceID = Service.ID 
        AND PSAGS2.ProviderID = Provider.ID AND PSAGS2.Type = ''GenderServed'' '
IF (@addressID > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' INNER JOIN ProviderAddress ON Provider.ID = ProviderAddress.ProviderID INNER JOIN Address ON ProviderAddress.AddressID = Address.ID '
END
DECLARE @SearchCondition NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SearchCondition = ''
IF @ProviderServiceToKeywordKeywordID IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    SET @SearchCondition = @SearchCondition + ' ProviderService.ProviderID IN (SELECT ProviderID FROM ProviderServiceToKeyword 
WHERE KeywordID IN (' + @ProviderServiceToKeywordKeywordID + ') AND ServiceID = '+CAST(@ServiceID AS VARCHAR(50))+') AND '
END
IF @GenderServed IS NOT NULL AND @GenderServed <> 0 AND @GenderServed <> -1
BEGIN 
    SET @SearchCondition =  @SearchCondition + '  PSAGS2.TypeTableID = ' + CAST(@GenderServed AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' AND '
END
IF @AgeGroupServed IS NOT NULL AND @AgeGroupServed <> 0 AND @AgeGroupServed <> -1
BEGIN 
    SET @SearchCondition =  @SearchCondition + ' PSAGS1.TypeTableID = ' + CAST(@AgeGroupServed AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' AND '
END
IF @ServiceID IS NOT NULL AND @ServiceID <> 0 AND @ServiceID <> -1 
BEGIN 
    SET @SearchCondition =  @SearchCondition + ' Service.ID = ' + CAST(@ServiceID AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' AND '
END
IF @ServiceCategoryID IS NOT NULL AND @ServiceCategoryID <> 0 AND @ServiceCategoryID <> -1 
BEGIN 
    SET @SearchCondition =  @SearchCondition + ' Service.CategoryID = ' + CAST(@ServiceCategoryID AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' AND '
END
IF @ProviderIsSlidingPaymentScale IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    SET @SearchCondition =  @SearchCondition + ' Provider.IsSlidingPaymentScale = ' + CAST(@ProviderIsSlidingPaymentScale AS VARCHAR(7)) + ' AND '
END
IF (@addressID > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @SearchCondition =  @SearchCondition + ' ProviderAddress.IsPrimary = 1 AND EXISTS (SELECT ''X'' FROM Address A2 WHERE A2.ID = '
+ CAST(@addressID AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' AND ( SQRT( ( (69.1 * (Address.Latitude - A2.Latitude)) * (69.1 * 
(Address.Latitude - A2.Latitude)) ) + ( (53.0 * (Address.Longitude - A2.Longitude)) * 
(53.0 * (Address.Longitude - A2.Longitude)) ) ) <= ' + CAST(@proximity AS VARCHAR(15)) + ') )  AND '
END
IF @SearchCondition <> ''
BEGIN
    SET @SearchCondition = LEFT(@SearchCondition, LEN(@SearchCondition) - 4)
    SET @SearchCondition = ' WHERE ' +  @SearchCondition
END
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @SearchCondition + ' ORDER BY Provider.Name'
PRINT @SQL
--EXEC sp_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail why Dynamic Linq and Predicate Builder are unsuitable?

Comment: stick it all in a stored procedure and call that from EF. (you could call this sweeping it under the rug, but a DBA would call it best practice :) )

Comment: @gbjbaanb Isn't that kinda what he's already doing now?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but if he's just trying to replace working SQL with LINQ for 'elegance' then he's missing something (probably something else to occupy his time productively). At least this way allows his C# code to look all nicely C# without that nasty, nasty SQL.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would not assert that both options are not suitable, though I would love an example of how they would be applied to my scenario joining multiple tables.

Comment: The presence of joins shouldn't matter, unless you're using the dynamic parameters to make the join.  If you're doing that, there may be some problems with your design; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect

Comment: @gbjbaanb We could keep it as a stored procedure, moving it out to Linq is an effort to keep things consistent though-out our codebase.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good enough reason, unless you intend to eventually replace the database with something else, like PostGres.

Comment: I don't see anything in your Stored Procedure that would preclude the use of Dynamic Linq.  You might not even need Dynamic Linq.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm supporting a SaaS app, long term it is a possibility that the application could transition away from MSSQL. Though, it certainly isn't an immediate initiative. With regard to your comment about the inner-platform effect - I think that you're absolutely right! Sadly, I jumped into this one mid-cycle - so we're paying down a large amount of technical debt.

Answer (score 3):

Your Dynamic SQL has:

1. One optional JOIN clause (When addressID is set) - but is never projected in the SELECT
2. Multiple optional WHERE clauses - all AND appended

Therefore, you don't need a query builder, you can use plain LINQ:

- That JOIN clause should be converted into a WHERE clause using `any` (which converts to the SQL `exists` statement)
- Your other JOINs should also be avoided and instead use `any`

For example:

```
void MagicTableQuery(int addressID, decimal proximity, int[] ProviderServiceToKeywordKeywordIDs, long? ServiceId, ...)
{
    var query = db.Provider;
    if (addressID > 0)
        values = values.Where(p => 
            db.ProviderAddress.Any(pa =>   
                pa.ProviderID == p.ID &&
                pa.IsPrimary == 1 &&
                db.Address.Any(a => 
                    a.ID = pa.AddressID &&
                    db.Address.Any(a2 =>
                        a2.ID = addressID &&
                        (~SqrtMathsHere...) <= proximity
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    
    if (ProviderServiceToKeywordKeywordIDs != null && 
        ProviderServiceToKeywordKeywordIDs.Length > 0 &&
        ServiceId.HasValue)
        values = values.Where(p =>
            db.ProviderServices.Any(ps => 
                ps.ProviderID == p.ID &&
                ps.ServiceId == ServiceId.Value
            ) &&
            db.ProviderServiceToKeyword(k =>
                ProviderServiceToKeywordKeywordIDs.Contains(k.KeywordID)
            )
        );

    //etc...

    var orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
    return orderedQuery.Select(...); //SELECT DISTINCT Provider.ID, Provider.Name, '''' AS IndividualName, ParentProviderID, NoteMultiLingualFieldID,ProviderGroupID 
}
```

---

Depending on performance also, you might have a second query for when you are searching by address, where you drive by the address table, find the associated matching providers, then apply the other filters.